# Python MadLib. NameError

Tags: python

I am a beginner python programmer, writing a madlib program for class. I have required the program to read from a file and then find the words that need to be replaced in "[]". I ask the user to provide me with words and then try to replace them. However when I try line.replace("[noun]",noun) it gives me an error:

> "NameError: name 'line' is not defined"

Here is my code:

```
def madLibOne():
    #Function opens up a file that contains the madlib.
    madLib1 = open('MadLibOne.txt', 'r')
    madLib1.readline()
    #Reads the file and asks user for input in what type of words they want inputted.
    weekday = input("Enter a weekday: ")
    adjective = input("Enter an adjective: ")
    food = input("Enter a food: ")
    location = input("Enter a location: ")
    favoriteprof = input("Enter the name of your favorite Proffessor: ")
    sumOfMoney = eval(input("Enter a sum of money: "))
    #Itterates through the file and replaces all words with user input
    for i in madLib1:
        line.replace("[weekday]",weekday)
        line.replace("[adjective]",adjective)
        line.replace("[food]",food)
        line.replace("[location]",location)
        line.replace("[favoriteProf]",favoriteprof)
        line.replace("[sumOfMoney]",sumOfMoney)
    #closes file
    madLib1.close()
```

Can someone please help me figure out what I'm doing wrong here?
Thank you

**EDIT**

Ok, so I replaced `i` variable with `line`, and now when I run it I get

> "TypeError: Can't convert 'int' object to str implicitly"

Because numbers can't be used for strings... Now what?

**EDIT 2**

```
def madLibOne():
#Function opens up a file that contains the madlib.
madLib1 = open('MadLibOne.txt', 'r')
madLib1.readline()
#Reads the file and asks user for input in what type of words they want inputted.
weekday = str(input("Enter a weekday: "))
adjective = str(input("Enter an adjective: "))
food = str(input("Enter a food: "))
location = str(input("Enter a location: "))
favoriteprof = str(input("Enter the name of your favorite Proffessor: "))
sumOfMoney = str(input("Enter a sum of money: "))
#Itterates through the file and replaces all words with user input
for line in madLib1:
    line = line.replace("[weekday]",weekday)
    line = line.replace("[adjective]",adjective)
    line = line.replace("[food]",food)
    line = line.replace("[location]",location)
    line = line.replace("[favoriteProf]",favoriteprof)
    line = line.replace("[sumOfMoney]",sumOfMoney)
#closes file
madLib1.close()
```

When I run this, I get no errors, however the file still stays the same as before...

**EDIT 3**

For everyone who is giving me advice on how to open and read the file, I have that, now, help would be better on how to save the user provided input into the file so it can be read from later, or creating a new file.

Here is what the text file looks like http://prntscr.com/7hlyag

Comment: So if line.replace doesn't replace the actual text in the file, how would I get the file to contain the words that the user inputted?

Comment: why did you un-accept my answer?

Comment: My bad. I was just going through my old post because I was working on something and forgot how to do it.

Comment: sure, no problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iterated variable is name `i`, and not `line`.

Seems that you want to read from file and write to file. This is the easiest way:

```
import fileinput
weekday = input("Enter a weekday: ")
adjective = input("Enter an adjective: ")
food = input("Enter a food: ")
location = str(input("Enter a location: "))
favoriteprof = input("Enter the name of your favorite Professor: ")
sumOfMoney = str(input("Enter a sum of money: "))
for line in fileinput.FileInput("MadLibOne.txt",inplace=1):
    line = line.replace("[weekday]",weekday)
    line = line.replace("[adjective]",adjective)
    line = line.replace("[food]",food)
    line = line.replace("[location]",location)
    line = line.replace("[favoriteProf]",favoriteprof)
    line = line.replace("[sumOfMoney]",sumOfMoney)
    print line
```

Alternatively:

```
weekday = input("Enter a weekday: ")
adjective = input("Enter an adjective: ")
food = str(input("Enter a food: "))
location = str(input("Enter a location: "))
favoriteprof = str(input("Enter the name of your favorite Proffessor: "))
sumOfMoney = str(eval(input("Enter a sum of money: ")))

#Values are:
# weekday = "Sunday"
# adjective = "Fun"
# food = "Beef"
# location = "Here"
# favoriteprof = "Kurland"
# sumOfMoney = "217"

with open('MadLibOne.txt', 'r') as madLib1:
    with open('MadLibOne_new.txt', 'w') as madLib1_new:
        for line in madLib1:
            line = line.replace("[weekday]",weekday)
            line = line.replace("[adjective]",adjective)
            line = line.replace("[food]",food)
            line = line.replace("[location]",location)
            line = line.replace("[favoriteprof]",favoriteprof)
            line = line.replace("[sumOfMoney]",sumOfMoney)
            madLib1_new.writelines(line)
```

The text file contains:

> “How are you?”
>   Today is Sunday! It is very Fun.
>   I like to eat Beef, while I [verb].
>   I’m supposed to be in class but I’m at Here.
>   My proffessor is Kurland. And he owes me 217.

Don't forget to correct the typo in professor , and to replace `[verb]`

Comment: @Dmitrik I added a code example with you input and the output

Comment: Thank you @omerbp. I don't think I can yet, since I'm a new user, but I would up your post :P Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use the [with statement](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#with) to open a file.

```
from __future__ import with_statement #if you are using python2

def madLibOne():
    words = ["[weekday]","[adjective]","[food]","[location]","[favoriteProf]","[sumOfMoney]"]
    weekday = str(input("Enter a weekday: "))
    adjective = str(input("Enter an adjective: "))
    food = str(input("Enter a food: "))
    location = str(input("Enter a location: "))
    favoriteprof = str(input("Enter the name of your favorite Proffessor: "))
    sumOfMoney = str(input("Enter a sum of money: "))
    #Open the file
    with open('MadLibOne.txt', 'r') as f:
        with open('output.txt', 'w') as o:
            #Iterate over each line
            for line in f:
                newline = line
                newline = newline.replace("[weekday]",weekday)
                newline = newline.replace("[adjective]",adjective)
                newline = newline.replace("[food]",food)
                newline = newline.replace("[location]",location)
                newline = newline.replace("[favoriteProf]",favoriteprof)
                newline = newline.replace("[sumOfMoney]",sumOfMoney)
                o.write(newline)
```

Also, your function seams to be incomplete, after replacing the text you may want to save it somewhere but that part is fully missing in your function.

Comment: Yes, that is not the complete code, I also have 4 other madlib functions and a main function where everything is called from. If that answers your question. 
However I already know how to open the file, now I just need to write it to a new file, using the text in the old text with the new inputted words

Comment: I have updated the code to include the file writing part. P.S. I noticed that you know how open the file but I have suggested to do it using the with statement  and a simple for loop to iterate on each line of it instead file.open(), file.readline() and file.close().

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I did not know about that. However the new code does not create the new file with the edited text. Still saves it as the words [food] instead of what the user would input

Comment: Sorry, never change the value of line if you are iterating on it! Now should work.

Comment: However, this code is extremely ugly. It's ok only to show you how to approach the task.

Comment: Right now, I don't need it to look beautiful, just working. Thank you :P @alec_djinn